# Is storing 5000 JSON objects memory heavy?

Tags: javascript

I am wondering if it is good idea to store an array of 5000 simple JSON objects (each object having `id` and `name`) memory heavy? Should I delete those after I use them, to clear some space in the memory?

Comment: Take some JSON for 5000 objects, paste it into your favorite editor, save it and see what the resulting file size is.

Comment: It's probably not reasonable to offer a "one sized fits all" answer to this, but tools like this should help you https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis?hl=en

Comment: also depends on the device you are using it on. browser / mob?

Comment: @JasonSperske, this is great article! I will dive into this.

Comment: @naveen, browser on stationary computer.

Comment: "browser on stationary computer", I assume this isn't what you mean http://cdn.displays2go.com/images/zoom/csltbla1.rw_preview.jpg :)

Comment: You don't have a "JSON object". JSON is a string. JSON is always a string. Always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming its a JSON string or that you are storing it in browser - localStorage/sessionStorage (using JSON.stringify) here is a small example on calculating the string size

```js
var items = [];
for (i = 1000000; i < 1005000; i++) {
  items.push({
    id: i,
    name: "Sooooooooooooome Biiiiiiiggggggggg naaaaaaaaaame_" + i
  });
}
var json = JSON.stringify(items);
var jsonSize = byteCount(json);

console.log("Size:", jsonSize, "KB");

function byteCount(s) {
  return (encodeURI(s).split(/%..|./).length - 1) / 1024;
}
```

It won't be more than 400KB. You really have to decide on how to proceed. That  depends on a lot of factors like device, internet speed, how frequently the data is used...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function to calculate the size of the object and decide for yourself is heavy in your system or not. If you are going to have repeated objects you can take a look to [javascript flyweight pattern](https://gist.github.com/addyosmani/2668755)for example:

```js
var obj = {
  name: "john",
  surname: "doe"
};

function memorySizeOf(obj) {
    var bytes = 0;

    function sizeOf(obj) {
        if(obj !== null && obj !== undefined) {
            switch(typeof obj) {
            case 'number':
                bytes += 8;
                break;
            case 'string':
                bytes += obj.length * 2;
                break;
            case 'boolean':
                bytes += 4;
                break;
            case 'object':
                var objClass = Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1);
                if(objClass === 'Object' || objClass === 'Array') {
                    for(var key in obj) {
                        if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
                        sizeOf(obj[key]);
                    }
                } else bytes += obj.toString().length * 2;
                break;
            }
        }
        return bytes;
    };

    function formatByteSize(bytes) {
        if(bytes < 1024) return bytes + " bytes";
        else if(bytes < 1048576) return(bytes / 1024).toFixed(3) + " KiB";
        else if(bytes < 1073741824) return(bytes / 1048576).toFixed(3) + " MiB";
        else return(bytes / 1073741824).toFixed(3) + " GiB";
    };

    return formatByteSize(sizeOf(obj));
};

console.log(memorySizeOf(obj));
```

Comment: There's a stray recursive call in there whose result I assume you meant to add to the size.

Comment: The recursive call is if the object contains another object or an array of objects

Comment: Yes, but you don't use the result of it. You need to add it to the size of the caller.

Comment: var bytes is outside sizeOf, when you enter inside an object you call sizeOf, when the recursion end resolve call stack and you have all the sizes of primitive types (no matter the depth) and sum then in the total size.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I've overlooked that while on my phone. :-)